# What does the number following fieldWeight mean in Solr debug explain?

Tags: solr

When I read the debug explain in Solr, there is one number following "fieldWeight in", like:

```
<str name="2531072">
3.1245635 = (MATCH) weight(
```

**title:epic in 111**

```
) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
      3.1245635 =
```

**fieldWeight in 111**

```
, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        6.249127 = idf(docFreq=4, maxDocs=952)
        0.5 = fieldNorm
```

**(doc=111)**

```
</str>
```

I wonder what that bold number means, how does solr get that number?
I can understand freq, docFeq, maxDoc termFreq, but only confused by this number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This number is the internal id of the document and doesn't affect the score. It's only a debugging info. The mailing list of Lucene gives [this information](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/What-is-the-quot-docs-quot-number-in-Solr-explain-query-results-for-fieldnorm-td3986172.html).

Comment: Thanks. I am still little confused about that "the internal id of the document", why there is only one id? I thought there should be multiple documents which has the term of the keyword.

Comment: You have a different score for each document. In your example document with name `2531072` has the score `3.1245635` and the internal id `111`. All doc has its own score, name and id. So you will have different internal id for each document that you get.

Comment: Thanks, so it is just another id used by lucene, similar to my document id field used by solr.